# R forecast function error

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to use the forecast function (forecast package in R) and running into problem.  Consider the following example:

```
library(forecast)
fit=arima(WWWusage,order=c(1,1,1))
fcast=forecast(fit)
plot(fcast)
```

At the forecast step, I am getting the error message:

```
Error in .forecast.transform(x, xv, a, h, 1) : 
  argument "xv" is missing, with no default
```

This happens even if I replace `arima` by `Arima` or `auto.arima` functions in the `forecast` package.

Comment: I can't reproduce.  Your code works fine, except that the last line has a typo - it should be `plot(fcast)`.

Comment: My guess is that you have loaded another package with a `forecast` function which is clashing with the forecast package.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Andrie and Rob for your helpful suggestions.  I have fixed the problem, but not sure how.  I installed an update to RStudio and reinstalled the forecast library and it worked! Maybe something got messed up recently.

Also, I want to take this opportunity to thank you, Rob, for developing this extremely useful R package.